# How do I find out what called my shared function

Tags: vb.net, function

I have a function in vb.net that is shared. At one point it throws an error that says an 'open datareader already exists'. But this function is called from several different places in the program. How can I find out which part of the program called the function when it errors out?

Comment: If you're not multithreading, use the call stack.

Comment: Can you please post the method(function).

Comment: [SyncLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement) -- [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim)

Comment: I tried using the call stack window, but it just stays empty the whole time I'm running the program.

Comment: You should be able to inspect the call stack of the exception

Answer (score 0):

You go to the Debug menu, show the Exceptions window, put a tick next to CLR exceptions and then run your program until it errors. As soon as the exception is raised VS will break, you will be able to see the call stack, and find out where the code was before. Note that this causes VS to stop on every exception, handled or not; it can become tedious to get to where you want to be - untick the "always break when this type of exception is thrown" in the exception helper if you just keep getting irrelevant exceptions breaking before this error you're trying to chase

It sounds like you're perhaps not creating/disposing of your DB access resources properly, especially if this is a static/shared context. Are you trying to reuse one DB connection? It wouldn't hurt to post the code of the faulting module